# Creating a virtual display on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, xorg, pdf, qt

I have an Ubuntu Server (18.04.4) VM, with a FreeNAS machine running [bhyve](https://www.ixsystems.com/documentation/freenas/11.2/virtualmachines.html) as the host for virtualization. I am building a service to headlessly save web pages to PDF using [wkhtmltopdf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/wkhtmltopdf.1.html). When invoking wkhtmltopdf, I get the following error message:

```
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Could not connect to any X display.
```

This happens whether I'm using the [software wrapper](https://github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf/) I found or invoking it directly from a shell:

```
wkhtmltopdf https://google.com pdfs/google.com.pdf
```

How do I configure my server so that commands like the above work without modification?

Comment: I'm not sure of the terminology surrounding my question (I have worked very little with X11 or windowing systems or desktop environments) so I'm not confident that I'm asking the right question  or asking in the right way. I'm happy to edit the question if I can get some clarity on exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more searching, I found [an issue](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2037) that reports that the wkhtmltopdf version included in Ubuntu has a version of qt that doesn't work in "headless" mode out of the box. By installing the [latest version](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/) from GitHub, I was able to get a version that does work headless:

```
$ wkhtmltopdf --version               
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5 (with patched qt)
```

Apparently compiling from source can also have the same desired effect, or running it with `xvfb-run` (not possible without changing the code I'm importing that calls wkhtmltopdf).